# In U14s Rugby (UK) is it possible to score a pushover try from a scrum?

Tags: rules, rugby

I'm sure I've seen suggestions that for anyone U19 or lower, the greatest distance a scrum can be legally pushed is 1.5 meters.

Can this please be confirmed? A reference would be great.

If true, does this mean that one cannot score a push-over try from a scrum, since these must start a minimum 5 meters from a try line?

Or is there an exception somewhere in the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pushover try cannot be scored under-19 or below.

Similarly, a penalty try from a scrum cannot be awarded because a pushover try was never a possibility.

As you've worked out, because a scrum must begin centred 5m from the try line, the 1.5m push limit prevents a pushover try.

*note:* there's also an under-19 law which forbids a team from deliberately keeping the ball in the scrum, which would make a pushover try nearly impossible in itself.

No exemption exists, **however** referees aren't always clued in on the laws and pushover tries/scrum penalty tries will occasionally be awarded in error.

[Source: world rugby under-19 law variations](http://laws.worldrugby.org/?variation=1&language=EN)

Comment: FWIW I'm finding the link you posted particularly useful. Thanks once again.

Comment: Niall, I agree completely about the pushover try, however as a referee I would consider a penalty try option from a scrum because of foul play.  For example diving on the ball in the scrum when a four man overlap exists.  I referee in RFU land and would be interested to see a link to the bit about penalty tries.